# Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'roman";"' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: javascript, css, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

**Error while executing filter ConvertFontToSpanFilter - InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'roman";"' is not a valid attribute name.**

I have this error showing trying to call in the other Telerik Editor.
I use Telerik Editor for update and Add.
Now i have identified the issue as the below code.

```
<span style="font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 7pt; line-height: normal; font-family: " times="" new="" roman";"="">
</span>
```

and then changed it to.

```
<span style="font-variant-numeric: normal;font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 7pt; line-height: normal;font-family:Times New Roman">
</span>
```

I use Sql Server DB it has a column data type of **ntext** even if i try to remove the ***font-family: " times="" new="" roman";"=""*** it still comes back in the Editor and i don't know why.

This ***font-family: " times="" new="" roman";"=""*** is showing every time in the editor if i try to remove or update.

I am using Database First Approach of Entity Framework.

Comment: try `font-family:'Times New Roman'">` It has to be in quotes. Recommended to not have inline styles

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an issue with quotes

For example
This HTML

```
<p style="font-family:"Times New Roman"">...</p>
```

is interpreted as

```
<p style="font-family:" times="" new="" roman="">...</p>
```

Why is it so? Because the values of HTML attributes are surrounded by Quotes ([***"***]  or [***'***]). If the value itself contains a quote, the browser will interpret it as the end of the value and after the following white-space a new attribute should begin.

To prevent this, use single quotes around the font name:

```
<p style="font-family:'Times New Roman'">...</p>
```

or us single quotes around the attribute value

```
<p style='font-family:"Times New Roman"'>...</p>
```

or better (but might not apply to your case). Use CSS classes and Stylesheets

```
<p class="roman">...</p>



<style>
.roman {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
</style>
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I commented. Not worth an answer

Comment: i've tried this p style="font-family:'Times New Roman'">...</p> but still it shows font-family: " times="" new="" roman";"=""